# ElasticSearch prevent html tags from being searchable

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a text that is tagged by a different application. I don't want queries for these tags to be returned when queried for.

I tried using html_strip but I was still able to search these tags.

Example of the tags could vary but they're similar to `<PERSON>Freddy</PERSON>`.
I also tried with `<span>Freddy</span>` and in both results I could search for either *span* or *PERSON* and get the result without these words appearing anywhere else.

What am I doing wrong?

Index mapping:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties":{
        "text":{
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
        }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "html_strip"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query

```
{
    "query":{
        "match":{
            "text":"span"
        }
    },
    "highlight":{
        "fields":{
            "text":{}
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
..
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "my_index",
                "_type": "wat",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.39556286,
                "_source": {
                    "text": "Hello <span>Freddy</span>"
                },
                "highlight": {
                    "text": [
                        "Hello <<em>span</em>>Freddy</<em>span</em>>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
...
```

Comment: it seems you have a typo in your mapping: `analzer` should read `analyzer`

Comment: @Val Thanks for pointing this out. I changed to analyzer but it didn't resolve the issue..

Comment: Did you delete the index, recreated it and reindexed your data?

Comment: @Val Yes I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here; first, `mapping` should be `mappings`, and you are missing the type when you declare the mappings (so your type `wat` isn't actually getting that mapping at all). You can use this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "wat": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "html_strip"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use the [get mapping api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html) to confirm that you see the mapping for the type `wat` like you expect.

Then if you index `Hello <span>Freddy</span>`, and search `Hello Freddy`, you will see this result. The term that's stored is `Hello Freddy`, but you will see the `span` tags in the search result, because the result returns the source (the value you indexed), not the analyzed terms. (You will also see the same result if you search `Hello <span>Freddy</span>`, but that's because the query text is analyzed in the same way as the indexed text.)

Note that since you've used the `keyword` tokenizer, you will get no results if you search `Hello` or `Freddy`. If you want to search within the string, instead of searching the full string (or wildcard, regexp, etc.), you should use a different tokenizer (like the `standard` tokenizer).

Another warning: the `html_strip` filter seems to only filter valid html tags (so it won't work for `<PERSON>`). You can probably use the [pattern filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you! solved the issue + great advice on the tokenizer and pattern filter :)