# How to store in elasticsearch a document without HTML?

Tags: html, elasticsearch, mapping

I want to index a document that contains chinese characters/words. In some fields there is as well some HTML tags.

I used "html_strip" to avoid the HTML to be indexed but my problem is that the document is stored with the HTML in elasticsearch. This is my index settings and mappings:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1, 
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "ch_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer",
          "char_filter":  [ "html_strip" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "qa": {
      "properties": {
        "comment_desc": {
          "type":     "text",
          "analyzer": "ch_analyzer"
        },
        "article_title": {
          "type":     "text",
          "analyzer": "ch_analyzer"
        },
        "article_desc": {
          "type":     "text",
          "analyzer": "ch_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }, 
    "sport": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type":     "text",
          "analyzer": "ch_analyzer"
        },
        "content": {
          "type":     "text",
          "analyzer": "ch_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For example I have the following content:

```
"<p><br/>台灣人，奧運直播，使用PPStream，(PPS網路電視)，觀看同步奧運實況</b>!"
```

It is in fact indexed but it will be stored as is.

What change should I bring to my mappings to remove the HTML part in the **stored** document?
What can I do to store this text in my Elasticsearch stripped of its HTML component?

Comment: Maybe duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903243/elasticsearch-prevent-html-tags-from-being-searchable

Comment: No a duplicate of this question. I succeed to make it non searchable I just want to store it in a way that I don't have HTML tags in my stored document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this on Elasticsearch (rather than as a preprocessing step), you have to use an [ingest node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html). There's not any [ingest processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest-processors.html) that does exactly what you want, so you would have to use a script processor or write a plugin to do it.

Depending on your use case, it may be easier to do this in a pre-processing step (with code in your language of choice).